# In this code what this customer parameter means

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, code, geturl

In this code what this **customer** parameter mean

```
$this->helper('customer')->getRegisterPostUrl();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I want to say that you have a lot of question about how Magento works. I like the spirit.

The method `helper()` that you call from inside a block, that is the same as calling `Mage::helper()` is a factory.
It returns you the instance of a class. A helper in this case.

The method `Mage::helper` looks like this:

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

This means that the class instance you get it will be a singleton. You will get the same class instance every time.

This method recieves a parameter `$name`. Based on this name Magento identifies the class that needs instatiating.  `$helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);`

If you go deeper in the method `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getHelperClassName` you will see this:

```
public function getHelperClassName($helperName)
{
    if (strpos($helperName, '/') === false) {
        $helperName .= '/data';
    }
    return $this->getGroupedClassName('helper', $helperName);
}
```

this means that if the parameter does not contain a slash `/data` will be added to the parameter.
so `$this->helper('customer')` is the same thing as `$this->helper('customer/data')`.

If you look further in the `getGroupedClassName` method...you will probably get lost :). I know I did at first.

But I will explain a bit how it works.
In the config.xml of a module you have under the `<global>` tag, definitions of models, blocks and helpers. like this

```
<helpers>
    <module_alias>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
    </module_alias>
</helpers>
```

When receiving a parameter like `customer/data` magento looks for the class node: config->global->helpers->customer->class.
In this case it will be `Mage_Customer_Helper` and appends to it what's after the slash in an uc first form. In this case `Data`.
So the class name is `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data`.
This class gets instantiated and the instance is returned.

Answer (score 3):

This is the alias for the Helper class used, this alias is used to build the class that is loaded to run the function specified.

In this case the helper alias for customer maps to `Mage_Customer_Helper`. Since only the class alias is specified the function getHelperClassName will append /data to load the default Helper class with the name: `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data`, the autoloader will then load the file `Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php`.

Answer (score 3):

Within templates `$this->helper()` gets translated to `Mage::helper()`

So this code means this is a call to `Mage::helper('customer')`, which gets translated to `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data` (or any class that rewrites it) in the backend.

If you're curious how this is done have a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getHelperClassName()`